# how to populate foreign key column in SequelizeJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sequelize.js

I have a database using sql in which User is associated to Account with userId as foreign key.I want to populate that foreign key column.I have tried to search about setters and getters in sequelize but there was not much to get help from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a few ways

### Setting the id manually

```
 const acct = await Account.create({/* ... */}); // could also find, if that's your use case
 const user = await User.create({ accountId: acct.id, /* ... */ });
```

### Sequelize functions

Assuming that you've setup your associations like this

```
 User.hasMany(Account)
 Account.belongsTo(User)
```

You can

```
 // assume `acct` is in scope
 const user = await User.create({/* ... */});
 await user.addAccount(acct);
```

You can also do it the other way around

```
 await account.setUser(user);
```

(also note that i'm using await which only works in async functions, but this is all possible with promises, too)